# iOS Charts Swift bar graph exceeds beyond view

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I have a problem with the Charts library. The problem I am facing is that the bar graph is not "fit" within the borders of my view. The following image shows that, the both first and last bar are cut into half and label of the highest bar is also partially cut.

[Bars and labels are cut along the graph borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW17f.png)

When I search online, I got the following thread https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/353 which seems to describe the exact same issue.

I use a simple dataset with some random numbers at 6 indices. The data is added to the chart as follows:

```
let values: [Int] = [5, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2]
var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry]

for i in 0..<values.count {
    let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(values[i]))
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}

let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Count")
let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
barChartView.data = chartData
```

Hopefully someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a bug in the library with regards to calculating the xAxis minimum and maximum.

You can manually set the xAxis minimum and maximum to prevent the first and last bars to be shown in half.

Add the below line of code, it should work perfectly fine.

```
yourBarChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = -0.5;
yourBarChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(yourAxisDataList.count) - 0.5;
```

Comment: Thanks, work likes a charm! I will mark this answer as right, as I expect more people to have this problem. Although ashmi123 provided an appropriate answer for the label problem.

Comment: Between are you sure you are using the latest library version?  Since this bug was fixed in  v2.2.5 and there is no need to add this code. I have also checked this in one of my app with the new version and it's working as expected.

Comment: For version in branch Chart3.0-Swift2.3 this hack is still valid. Thanks!

Comment: @VikramEzhil Im using the latest version of Charts and was having this problem.

Comment: @Aditya The most recent version of Charts has this bug, guess the bug tracking and fixing by the creators is very inconsistent for this library.

Answer (score 9):

you can add the offset to Top and bottom view as below :

```
 barChartView.extraTopOffset = 40.0f;
 barChartView.extraBottomOffset = 10.0f;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to have fixed the labelling issue. The problem of the half bars unfortunately remains, it is not fixed by setting extraLeftOffset/extraRightOffset. When I run the demo app it seems to be displaying the bar graphs correctly.

Comment: can you show image for that exactly where it cut off?

Comment: The link in my previous post still holds for the cutoff. It seems to cut the bars exactly in half. Changing the size of the viewcontroller does not seem to help. http://i.stack.imgur.com/iW17f.png

Answer (score 1):

You can try, editting the value of xAxis of your bargraph with values between -0.99... to -0.5.
Check this example:

[image]

With: yourBarChart.xAxis.axisMinimum = -0.5

[image]

With: yourBarChart.xAxis.axisMinimum = -0.99

Answer (score 0):

If it is vertical Bar chart

```
barChartView.xAxis.spaceMin   = 5.0f;
barChartView.xAxis.spaceMax   = 5.0f;
```

if it is Horizantal bar chart

```
barChartView.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.0
```

or 
barChartView.rightAxis.